# Meaning of "Der Weise ist alt"

Tags: grammar-identification

A questio on Duolingo was to translate:

> The wise man is old.

The answer was given as:

> Der Weise ist alt.

Der Weise translates into 'the wise' on Google translate, so by what grammar rule is the 'Man' being the noun implied in the sentence?

Comment: You have noted the masculine article?

Comment: Does the masculine article imply that it is talking about the man?

Comment: In case no other context is given, yes. Of course, *der weise Mann* is equally valid (as would be *die weise Frau*) and more robust against gender discussion. But as always: a single machine translations is typically a poor justification for a question and requires additional research or thoughts.

Comment: I think the issue in the lack of extra information is that it's not clear what to search so I could add more detail here. Grammer identification, hence that's what was chosen. However I'll keep what you said in mind.

Comment: This phenomenon also exists in English. Do you know the movie [The Good, the Bad and the Ugly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly)?

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: @Paul Frost: I think "The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly" is a bit of an outlier, being a literal translation of the Italian title. (Ironically, in German, where the literal translation would make more sense, the distributors went in an entirely different direction.) A better example for English speakers is "adult" as an adjective vs. "adult" as a noun. In English, it's more typical to use a nominalized adjective collectively: "Only the good die young."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I've had some experience with Duo myself, and while it's a good way to get started, some of their translation choices are a bit, let's say, questionable. The last I checked, Duo had their own forums for discussing questions, so you might want to check it if you get the question again.

The dictionary form for *Weise* (not to be confused with *Wiese*) is the adjective *weise*="wise", and *Weise* is what is called a nominalized adjective. To form a nominalized adjective in German, start with an adjective, decline it as if it was in front of a noun, and capitalize it. I don't know if you've covered adjective declension in Duo yet, if not then it's not really fair of them to include that example; like I said, questionable. The meaning of the noun is an example of a person or thing having the quality in question. For example *erwachsen* = "to grow up" -> (past participle) *erwachsen* = "grown up"/"adult" -> *der Erwachsene* = "the adult (male)". Another example (which I remember vividly from the opening scene of Horizon Zero Dawn): *ausstoßen* = "to eject" -> (past participle) *ausgestoßen* = "ejected"/"cast out" -> *der Ausgestoßene* = "the outcast (male)". There is a similar process in English, as noted in the comments, but the resulting noun usually has a different meaning.

These nominalized adjectives are declined according to gender, case, and strong vs. mixed vs. weak, like their adjective parents. You can also tell gender from the preceding article/determiner if present. When preceded by a definite article, they use the weak declension, so it's not possible to tell the gender from the word itself, but in that case the article itself tells you. So *der Erwachsene* = male adult, *die Erwachsene* = female adult. In your case, *der Weise* = "the wise (male) person" and *die Weise* = "the wise (female) person". DWDS lists some additional meanings for the related actual noun *Weiser*, either hand (on a clock) or road sign.

All that said, I think what Duo was trying to say was "wise man" as in "sage" or "magus", not the more generic "man who is wise". Did I mention their translations can be questionable?

PS. [Bruce Duncan's grammar site](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Edeutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html) has a good introduction to this material.